# Как предотвратить самопроизвольную transition анимацию в хроме при обновлении страницы? Есть решение без скриптов!

Tags: css, google-chrome

Я находил кучу подобных вопросов,но не увидел решения проблемы.

В общем есть например кнопка и ей задал `transition` анимацию . Все работает, но именно в хроме когда обновляешь страницу все анимации скачут. Например если у кнопки `паддинги` и белый цвет ссылки задали то при обновлении страницы `паддинги` анимируют со стандартных до заданных размеров и цвет ссылки кнопки со стандартного синего или фиолетового изменяется плавно до белого.

В ффоксе такого нет. можно задать анимацию  только при `:hover`,и проблема уходит,но появляется другая- когда убираешь мышку с кнопки,она без анимации возвращается на весто\к стандартным заданным размерам.

```css
body {
 background-color:#2e3436;
}
a {
 color:#ccc;
 text-decoration:none; 
}
/*---------/// UP BUTTON ///---------*/
.upbtn {
 position: fixed;
 bottom:30px;
 left:30px;
 display:block;
 transition: 0.3s;
 transition-timing-function:ease-in-out;
}
.upbtn:hover{
 transform: rotate(1deg);
 bottom:34px;
}
.upbtn a {
 border-radius:0 14px 0 14px;
 border:1px solid #ccc;
 padding: 5px 15px;
 opacity:0.3;
 transition: 0.3s;
 transition-timing-function:ease-in-out;
}
.upbtn a:hover {
 text-decoration:none;
 background-color:#ccc;
 color:#2e3436;
 opacity:1; 
 padding: 7px 19px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="upbtn"><a href="#top"><b>▲ ВВЕРХ</b></a>
 </div>
```

Comment: Довольно размытое описание проблемы, дайте пожалуйста примеры кода или ссылки на подобные вопросы, в которых есть пример кода. К сожалению прыжки элементов при анимации частое явление и конкретно ваш пример ничего не освещает

Comment: @alexoander спасибо,хоть кто-то отозвался.
p.s. вероятно чтобы увидеть эффект надо запускать код локально на компе И ПЕРЕЗАГРУЗИТЬ СТРАНИЧКУ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Наконец-то!!!!!! это случилось!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! я нашел простой ответ! Без js ! помогла [эта ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25404206/chrome-transition-fires-on-page-load-when-form-element-added)

В общем фишка в том, чтобы вынести нужные свойства из-за которых все пляшет из подключенных стилей с тег `style`

Например в моем примере надпись кнопки это ссылка и при загрузке страницы цвет ссылки НА ХРОМЕ плавно изменяется со стандартного синего/фиолетового на заданный во внешних стилях серый цвет. Надо просто вынести из внешних стилей в моем примере

`a {
    color:#ccc;
    text-decoration:none;
    }`

в тег `style` и после этого эти свойства докучать не будут!

Answer (score 2):

Да, Firefox не анимирует стартовые значения. А в обратную сторону анимация работает, когда transition задана у элемента. Чтобы при загрузке ничего не анимировалось, можно использовать `keyframes` или сделать то-то вроде:

```
.load * {
  -webkit-transition: none !important;
  -moz-transition: none !important;
  -ms-transition: none !important;
  -o-transition: none !important;
}
```

и

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $("body").removeClass("load");
});
```

Comment: извините за ответ пока голосовать не могу (новичек на сайте)
ответ помог,спасибо
а в чем был прикол ? неужели в хроме не могут это исправить, при чем я где-то читал что это с 24 версии тянется.. может это не баг а фича?)

Comment: на мой взгляд - скорее фича, а в ff - поведение неправильное, однако может быть и другое мнение, возможно поэтому так до сих пор.

Comment: [таки баг всё-таки.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25404206/chrome-transition-fires-on-page-load-when-form-element-added)

Answer (score 0):

В конце тега `<body>` пишите тег `<script> </script>` с пробелом внутри - и всё готово.