# transition для ссылки работает не правильно

Tags: html, css

Проблема в том, что ссылки меняются не только при *hover*-е, но и просто при обновлении страницы. Т.е. изначально они синие, потом постепенно становятся серыми и приобретают объём и высоту из *body*.

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Kanit', sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 22px;
  color: #070707;
}

.menu__list {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.menu__list-link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #828282;
  transition: all 1.5s;
}

.menu__list-link:hover {
  color: #070707;
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu">
  <ul class="menu__list">
    <li class="menu__list-item">
      <a class="menu__list-link" href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu__list-item">
      <a class="menu__list-link" href="#">About me</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu__list-item">
      <a class="menu__list-link" href="#">Skills</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu__list-item">
      <a class="menu__list-link" href="#">Portfolio</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu__list-item">
      <a class="menu__list-link" href="#">Contacts</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Не могу понять, в чем проблема? В другом проекте, в аналогичной ситуации, всё работает. Загуглить так же не могу, потому что не знаю, как коротко описать данный вопрос.

[ссылка на видео](https://youtu.be/4rz2svIBMwI)

Comment: добавил html, в принципе все стандартно.

Comment: попробуйде явно задать color вместо all в transition

Comment: @GGO ничего в этом случае не меняется. проблема в том что при hover все нормально, цвет меняется. я не могу понять почему transition работает при обновлении страницы и начинает подтягивать стили с body и менять цвет со стандартного синего на заданный непосредственно в классификаторе ссылки.

Comment: Хотя я и не наблюдаю здесь описанного Вами эффекта, но могу догадываться в чём проблема. Решение же этой проблемы - двойная анимация вместо перехода. Другого решения я не видел, а с проблемой не Вы первый сталкиваетесь.

Comment: @UModeL добавил ссылку на видео, для наглядности

Comment: перенесите transition в свойство с hover

Comment: @Meth0d: на видео ссылки не синие, а лиловые (посещённые) - посмотрите в стилях что-то типа `a:visited { color: ... }`. Чую, что там трабла, ибо здесь в сниппете всё Ок работает, но здесь каждый раз заново документ при запуске создаётся и не запоминается браузером.

Comment: @GGO так тоже пробовал. тогда при наведении мыши на ссылку работает нормально, а при убирании цвет меняется мгновенно

Comment: @UModeL нашел ответ, проблема в браузере. Есть несколько решений. Нашел тут же на сайте. Спасибо Вам за помощь и переоформление. Впредь буду знать как оформлять вопросы.

Comment: @Meth0d: да, правильное оформление очень важно - позволяет сэкономить кучу времени отвечающим, а Вам получить ответ как можно быстрее. Если нашли решение проблемы, то дайте ссылку в комментарии или дополните в вопросе или даже можете на основании найденного решения дать ответ ниже самому себе - тут такое тоже можно, только ответ должен быть развёрнутым и подробным.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы при загрузке ничего не анимировалось, можно использовать `keyframes` или сделать что-то вроде:

```
.load * {
  -webkit-transition: none !important;
  -moz-transition: none !important;
  -ms-transition: none !important;
  -o-transition: none !important;
}
```

и

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $("body").removeClass("load");
});
```

Ответ найден в [этой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/582349/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-transition-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%B2-%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%82/582413#582413) теме. Спасибо [11111000000](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/189818/11111000000).